# "Hive Runtime Error while processing row" (only on MR)

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive

When testing out a query, we encounter the error below. Any hint on how to resolve this ?

I'm looking for guidance on ways that we might tune our Hive or MR settings to work around this.

Thanks

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable {"tweet_id":812547772591304704,"created_unixtime":1482561460050,"created_time":"Sat Dec 24 06:37:40 +0000 2016","lang":"it","displayname":"algidagilda","time_zone":"","msg":"fredcasualmente i fiocchi di neve sono le farfalle dellinverno
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:54)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:453)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:168)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1724)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:162)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error while processing writable {"tweet_id":812547772591304704,"created_unixtime":1482561460050,"created_time":"Sat Dec 24 06:37:40 +0000 2016","lang":"it","displayname":"algidagilda","time_zone":"","msg":"fredcasualmente i fiocchi di neve sono le farfalle dellinverno
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:543)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecMapper.map(ExecMapper.java:163)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Unterminated string at 237 [character 238 line 1]
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.onMalformedJson(JsonSerDe.java:412)
        at org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe.deserialize(JsonSerDe.java:174)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.readRow(MapOperator.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator$MapOpCtx.access$200(MapOperator.java:107)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MapOperator.process(MapOperator.java:534)
        ... 9 more

FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-2: Map: 3  Reduce: 1   HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please start hive using this command for more debugging

```
bin/hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DEBUG,console
```